# Mockito when().thenReturn() does not behave as expected when lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired)) is used

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit4, lombok

I have Spring class say

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {
    private final InternalService internalService;

    public Set<String> do(String anything) {
      Set<String> relevent = internalService.finaIntern(anything);
      return relevent;
    }
}
```

I am writing Unit Test case as below

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class TestMainServiceImpl {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainServiceImpl service;

    @Mock
    InternalService internalService;   

    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDo() { 
        Set<String> setData = new HashSet<>();
        setData.add("ABC");
        String a ="a";
        when(internalService.finaIntern(any(String.class))
                                  .thenReturn(setData);
        Set<String> result = service.do(a);
        assertTrue(!result.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

Here my testcase fails , but if I remove **final** form MainServiceImpl and do an explicit **@Autowired** like below

```
@Component
class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {
    @Autowired
    private InternalService internalService;
     .....
```

Here I am curious to know 
 1. How does my test case pass if I remove final keyword
 2. Is it a good practice to use @RequiredArgsConstructor , if yes then how and if no then also why ?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense... You are creating a mock and inject it into the testcase and not the `MainServiceImpl`. So either you aren't showing the code as you use or your code is really borked.

Comment: @M.Deinum Dues to security reason I cannot post actual code here , so I typed similar classes. It was a typo error .I have modified it.

Comment: You also have a double init, you are already running with the `MockitoJUnitRunner` but again init them in your `@before` method. You mus t init them ones (especially due to your final members).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum , When I remove @ RunWith annotation it worked fine , but why it did not worked when @ RunWith annotation was there . Its ok if JUnit was unable to change the final variable but , how does it effect the when().thenReturn() ?

Comment: because you are now telling a different mock then the `MainServiceImpl` has what to do. You end up with 2 mocks (due to double init, you end up with 2 mocks and only 1 of them is wired to the `MainServiceImpl` due to the `final` keyword. so either remove the `@RunWith` or remove the `Mockoti.initMocks in your `@BEfore` method, you really only want that to happen once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `lombok` nor Spring `@Autowired`
The combination of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` is the problem. Removing any of it and the behavior is as expected. You don't need both of them. In fact `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` exists only for the cases when you cannot use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, for example if you need to use `SpringRunner.class`.

Here is why it doesn't work.
First of all of your objects are instantiated. So both your `@Mock` is created and injected into you `@InjectMock` object:

Below you can see, that the new create mock (`mocks[0]`), `service` inside of `injectInto` and `mock` are the same object.

[image]

But then the initialization happens the second time.
So mockito create a new `@Mock` object, and the tries to inject it into your `@InjectMock` object, which is already instantiated. But failed to inject it to the field as long as it's final.
So here is what we have after the second initialization:

[image]
As you can see, now the mock object inside of your `testClassInstance` and the mock injected to your Object under test are different.

What about `@RequiredArgsConstructor`: for me it's totally ok to use it in the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your testcase should be like. You should not use

> MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

when you are using @InjectMock for the class under test. This works for @AllArgConstructor.

```
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    class TestMainServiceImpl {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainServiceImpl service;

    @Mock
    InternalService internalService;   


    @Test
    public void testDo() { 
        Set<String> setData = new HashSet<>();
        setData.add("ABC");
        String a ="a";
        when(internalService.finaIntern(any(String.class))
                                  .thenReturn(setData);
        Set<String> result = service.do(a);
        assertTrue(!result.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

Try the above method for writing testcase for @allArgConstructor and for @RequiredArgConstructor.  If this dosent work, you can try the below logic.

If you use only @Data annotation (lombok.Data) in your class, then constructor with only mandatory (final) fields, will be generated. It is because Data implies RequiredArgsConstructor. example :

```
@Data
@Component
class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {
private final InternalService internalService;
}
```

Annotation @Builder generates for us MainServiceImpl class which helps us create new MainServiceImpl

```
@Data
@Builder
@Component
class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {
private final InternalService internalService;
}
```